# How to call a method based from a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

newbie here.  This is an iPhone utility project.

First things first.  I have a protocol that is this:

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text :(BOOL)isOn;
@end
```

I implement this protocol in my MainViewController by doing this:

```
- (void)updateLabels:(NSString *)text :(BOOL)isOn {
    [nameLabel setText:text]; 
     if (isOn)
      [onLabel setText:(@"ON")];
     else
      [onLabel setText:(@"OFF")];
     }
```

Now I'm wanting to use the `updateLabels` method in my FlipsideViewController in a method called `buttonClick`.  How would I refer to the updateLabels method located in MainViewController?

Comment: EDIT:  Thanks for the answers.  What I'm trying to do is use a variable in place of the `@"foo"`.  Regardless of what I put in, the compiler says that `FlipsideViewController may not respond to '-updadeLabels`.  I'm quite stuck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your EDIT above, I think you might be confused about delegate protocols.

Delegation is where you have a second object, the delegate, that adopts the delegate protocol.  Then the FlipsideViewController object calls methods (which are part of that protocol) on the delegate object.  What this means is that FlipsideViewController shouldn't implement the FlipsideViewControllerDelegate protocol, and so you shouldn't be calling methods from that protocol on it.

Here's some more information on delegation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1

And some more on protocols:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW1

Comment: Edit: To those who find this question again, I found a way to do this.  You just need to do `self.delegate updateLabels:@"foo" "YES];`

Answer (score 2):

`[self updateLabels:@"foo" :YES];`

By the way, while it's possible to do an unnamed parameter to a method (like you have), it's generally considered bad practice without a very good reason otherwise. :)